# Find Broken Images Using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium

I need to test images on a webpage. 
How should I deal with the following situation:

1. To check whether all images are loaded.
2. To check if broken images are loaded.
3. To that the description in Alt="" if the image is not loaded.

Kindly suggest how should I do this.
I need a code in Java which works like the like given: http://tools.seochat.com/tools/broken-links-images-tool

Comment: Did you try any code? no one will give you ready made full code. You should try and share your code when you get problem.

Comment: Hi kate, I tried using following code which i took from web, i tried manipulating code but it was not successful.

Comment: Hello John, could you provide your code in the question?

Comment: Hi,I need a code in java which works like the like given below,http://tools.seochat.com/tools/broken-links-images-tool/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**With Selenium**

I am not sure Selenium should be used as a link/image checker. In an ideal world you would define which images are on a page, if the images exist you could check their ALT tag. Then your tests verifies those predefined situations are still there.

This [blog post](http://seleniumtestautomationtipsandtricks.blogspot.nl/2013/01/finding-elements-using-class-selector.html) shows how you can find images based on their ALT content:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[alt='Previous']"));
```

I get the feel you looking for some code that magically detects what images exist on a page and if they are correct. This is what some link checkers do, they check the source of an image or link exists. Then check if they have a ALT text, but do not check the correct value. The tool you linked to is a web-based tool and the magic happens on their back-end. You cannot re-use their work without the back-end code.

This [blog post](http://www.studyselenium.com/2014/01/how-to-find-broken-images-in-page-using.html) shows how you can loop tru all images on a page with Selenium in Java. If you combine that with the first blog post you can then check the ALT text:

```
public class findbrokenimages {
  static int invalidimg;
  static WebDriver driver ;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.get("http://ruchi-myseleniumblog.blogspot.in");
      invalidimg = 0;
      List allImages  = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
      System.out.println("Total  images are " + allImages.size());
      for (int i = 0; i < allImages.size(); i++) {
        WebElement img = (WebElement) allImages.get(i);
        if (img != null) {
          verifyimgActive(img);
        }
      }
      System.out.println("Total invalid images are " + invalidimg);
      driver.quit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  public static void verifyimgActive(WebElement img) {
    try {
      HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet(img.getAttribute("src")));
      if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200)
      invalidimg++;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Also look into the [.getAttribute()](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)) function of a WebElement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394828/how-to-get-the-value-of-an-attribute-using-xpath

**Open Source LinkCheckers**:

I think you are looking for something like this:

- Java: https://code.google.com/p/linkchecker/
- Python: http://wummel.github.io/linkchecker/

Comment: thanks Niels, working on it will get back to you if any problem.