# How to find Missing "Alt" Attribute or Value in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I would like to write program which search all images on webpage and looks if any images missing with alt attribute of value inside the attribute.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: See my answer on: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/11876/find-broken-images-using-selenium-ide