# UI automation with selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

What is right way to automate test cases to verify display of ui elements like product filters, images? Can we verify display using `IsDisplayed(locator)`?or it will be flaky test?

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/verifying-if-an-image-is-displayed-on-a-webpage

Answer (score 1):

You can have the following ways to identify the UI of the element

- **`isDisplayed()`** - To verify the elements gets displayed or not
- **`isEnabled()`** - To verify the web elements is enabled or not
- **`isSelected()`** - To verify the radio button and the combo box is selected or not.

Depends upon the type of the element you can use any of these methods to verify the UI of the elements. You can then assert by printing the output in the console

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the already mentioned methods I'd like to add that Images are actually tricky. Even if you check if the WebElement is displayed the image might be broken so I recommend to always check if the source is actually available.

Just use something along the lines of

```
public static Boolean checkSource(String Link) throws Exception{
     HttpUrlConnection Conn = (HttpUrlConnection) new URL(Link).openConnection();
     return Conn.getResponseCode() < 400;
}
```

That way you can reliably check your Image.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use `WebElement.isDisplayed()` to check if an element is visible.
Then, you can add another assert, which verifies text, and etc ...
If you create a good location strategy, your test will work.

Comment: For UI elements if  css attributes changes after particular action by user like if user clicks on link, css class is changed for link So if i assert class of element after click, is that good automation strategy?

Comment: Depends on test strategy/implementation. Each interaction with HTML change something. And yours asserts is to the end of tets, right?
So, the best practice is to maintain only locators/selectors, without change anything in your code implementation.

Comment: <div class="gridlist-toggle">
        <a href="#" id="grid" title="Grid View" class=""></a><a href="#" id="list" title="List View" class="active"></a>
    </div>

Comment: After link for grid view is clicked, class for grid view is active So can i assert class of grid view link after click to verify view ?As no message is displayed on webpage i am trying to test

Comment: After the click, message is not displayed? What change in all HTML?

Comment: after click class of view changes to active No change in html

Comment: Any visual changes of ALL HTML, after your action?

Comment: view of page changes from list to grid Product images are displayed in grid look

Comment: Ok, assert that. After y action, image positions are changed.

Answer (score 0):

It is also important to think about the selectors you use. Long XPath selectors will often break from little tweaks to the UI. Using an id or relative xpath will often save you from failing tests that result from minor edits.